# WebAPI 2 Best practices - Products and Categories

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am currently developing a WebAPI 2 project.

I have two models:

- "Product" with an identifier, a name and a category
- "Category" with an identifier, a name, and a list of products

On a web page I have to display all products, but by categories:

- Category 1 
  -- Product
  -- Product
  -- Product
- Category 2 
  -- Product
  -- Product

My question is: Iif I want to retrieve a list of populated categories from my WebAPI, did I:

- Create a controller "ProductsController" and implement a method that returns me an object of type IEnumerable of Category ?
- Or create a controller "CategoriesController" and implement a method that returns me an object of type IEnumerable of Category ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning Categories which happen to have products as children. I would implement this in the `CategoryController` (not CategoriesController). It should return `IQueryable` not IEnumerable.

```
public class CategoryController
{
    [Queryable]
    public IQueryable<Category> Get()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

That depends completely on how you organize your UI - i.e. your use cases. (Note that Controllers are not specific to any business logic questions, but only specific to physical web pages, or resources in case of an API.)

- If you have a page 'Categories' and want to see all products that belong to a specific category, then the `CategoryController` approach would be suitable.
- If you have a page 'Products' and you want to filter them by category, then the `ProductController` approach would be the way to go.
- If you want both, then implement both.

Answer (score 0):

you should create CategoryController  and return IQueryable instead of IEnumerable. because IQueryable is best for out-memory.

```
public IQueryable<Category> GetCategory()
{
   //your get logic here
}
```